# Generic return type based on generic input

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function with this signature:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    name: string; 
    value: T; 
}    

const foos: Foo<number>[] = [
    { name: "a", value: 1 },
    { name: "b", value: 2 }
];     

function getObjectFromFoos(arr: Foo<T>[]): { [key: string] : T} {
        return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            return {
                ...acc,
                [cur.name]: cur.value
            }
        }, {});
    }
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20T%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foos%3A%20Foo%3Cnumber%3E%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20value%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20value%3A%202%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getObjectFromFoos(arr%3A%20Foo%3CT%3E%5B%5D)%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%20%3A%20T%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20arr.reduce((acc%2C%20cur)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...acc%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcur.name%5D%3A%20cur.value%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Currently this gives the error

> Cannot find name 'T'

Is it possible to do this in typescript, without explicitly declaring that type T in the function generic?

ie.

I know that I can make this error going away by declaring it in the function generic:

```
function getObjectFromFoos<T>(arr: Foo<T>[]): { [key: string] : T} {
    {    
       //implmentation
    }


getObjectFromFoos<number>(foos);
```

But I don't want to do that, as then each time I call the function, I need to explicitly define the generic type, which should be be able to be inferred.

Comment: Works for me without the number (adding `<T>` and `var x = getObjectFromFoos(foos);
console.log(x)` at the bottom).

Comment: You have an extra `{` in the definition of `getObjectFromFoos`.

Comment: define `getObjectFromFoos` with type parameter `<T>` and call it without type parameter. typescript  use type argument inference. so you should not get any error. I checked it

Comment: @kabanus - Ah, your right. 

So the generic type can be inferred from an argument, it doesn't need to be explicity set on function call. You should post that as the answer.

Comment: Since this was just a typo I suggest you delete the question. No harm done.

Comment: @kabanus - It's not a typo (if you're referring to the extra brace?) . It was a misunderstanding on my part of how generic definitions on functions work.